# C# OpenXML 2.0 Replace EMPTY Bookmarks in Paragraphs AND Body

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, bookmarks

I tested many solutions, at legalcube.de (which was the best looking) and even the ones found here.

But, this is not working on my documents. My bookmarks are in part "Body", and not within paragraphs or tables, so the last given example throws exceptions while trying to cast the given body element as paragraph. Of course, I can handle the exception, but I do not know how to make the code working.

Is there any really working solution to replace EMPTY bookmarks with OpenXML?

Here is an example of my document structure using the Open XML 2.0 Productivity Tool:
http://abload.de/image.php?img=13-09-201318-35-08nsx2i.png

And the code of the element:
http://abload.de/image.php?img=13-09-201318-41-25eijdo.png

PS: Same question/problem as in Question [Replace bookmark contents in Word using OpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782436/replace-bookmark-contents-in-word-using-openxml), means, I also have the "greyed" boxes in my document.

With help of the productivity tool, I saw, that the structure is somewhat strange:
BookmarkStart is in Body, then, there is a paragraph. Within the paragraph, I found the BookmarkEnd.
Example:

```
<> w:bookmarkStart (BookmarkStart)  
  <> w:p (Paragraph)  
  <> w:pPr (ParagraphProperties)  
  <> w:r (Run)  
  <> w:r (Run)  
  <> w:r (Run)  
  <> w:bookmarkEnd (BookmarkEnd)
```

Is that a well-formatted OpenXML-File?